# SpEL: Inject a dynamically populated map into a constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-el

I am trying to inject a dynamically constructed map into a constructor parameter.

I have two classes `AuthHandler`, `MyAuthHandler`. MyAuthHandler constructs the Map which will be passed to AuthHandler constructor. There are overloaded constructors in AuthHandler, I want to create its instance using constructor that accepts only Map (authorities).

I tried below code but the map is always empty in AuthHandler class.

env.xml

```
    <bean id="Handler" class="com.test.AuthHandler">
        <constructor-arg name="authorities" type="java.util.Map" 
             value="#{ T(com.test.MyAuthHandler).getAccessControlMap() }" />
    </bean>
```

AuthHandler.java (from a dependency)

```
public class AuthHandler {

    private final Authority defaultAuthority;
    private final Map<String, Authority> authorities;

    public AuthHandler(Authority authority) {
        this(emptyMap(), authority);
    }

    public AuthHandler(Map<String, Authority> authorities) {
        this(authorities, new DenyAllAuthority());
    }

    AuthHandler(Map<String, Authority> authorities, Authority defaultAuthority) {
        this.defaultAuthority = defaultAuthority;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    ...
}
```

MyAuthHandler.java

```
public class MyAuthHandler {

    public static Map<String, Authority> getAccessControlMap() {
        // map will be created querying database
        String path = "api-path/*";
        Authority authority = new Authority("UserA");

        Map<String, Authority> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(path, authority);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use JavaConfig?

Comment: Thanks for looking, AuthHandler is from a dependency I cannot update it to use JavaConfig.

Comment: I tried with `@Value` and `Map<String, String>`, works fine. Suppose smth wrong with config.

Comment: You know that you can declare an `@Bean` method for any class, including third-party classes?

Comment: Thanks I used `@Bean` and it works fine, couldn't fix with XML though